# Netbeans - a method call becomes italic - and causing error

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

What does it mean in netbeans when a statement like the code below becomes all italic?

```
    MessageBox.show("test", "test");
```

I get the error below as well on runtime. But not when coding, just the ".show()" method that's not appearing in autocomplete. But the class is already in its appropriate folder and is already imported. What could be the problem here as well?

```
 Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: library.MessageBox.show
```

Complete code:

```
public class MessageBox {

    public static void show(String titleString, String messageString)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messageString, titleString, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: please double check the import statements

Comment: Fixed. Via Netbeans - created a temporary MessageBox2.java. Copied content from the original MessageBox.java. Then deleted the original file. Then renamed MessageBox2.java to MessageBox.java. It's fixed after that. Don't know exactly what happened though. As per my googling, could be a netbeans bug.

Comment: @ThilinaMD, I already checked. The method call works in some classes, and doesn't in others. This in the same project.

Comment: Possibly same problem and same fix. Check link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278718/stretchicon-class-doesnt-work-when-returned-from-a-method-causes-error

Answer (score 0):

The above code you provided runs fine on eclipse.

As you said you are using Netbeans and may be affected by a bug. Try this:

> Open the project properties, select the Build-Compiling, uncheck
>   "Compile on save" and rerun the application.

This will make sure all your source code becomes recompiled before running it.

Ref: https://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1647.html