# StretchIcon class doesn't work when returned from a method. Causes error

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, compiler-errors, imageicon

A direct call - `new StretchIcon(imageStr);` - works.

But **not** when returned from a method. Causes error.

```
public static ImageIcon getPhotoSI(String imageStr){
    return new StretchIcon(imageStr);
}
```

What could be the problem?

**[StretchIcon Link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/)**

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: library.StretchIcon.<init>
    at library.IImage.getPhotoSI(IImage.java:36)
    at Users.populateTable(Users.java:448)
    at FrmUsers.btnSearch_ActionPerformed(FrmUsers.java:455)
    at FrmUsers.access$600(FrmUsers.java:18)
```

Comment: The title is misleading as there is a code compilation error. Solve that before trying to run the code. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I note the title has been edited (minimally). Any chance of that MCVE appearing soon? While you're at it, post the errors or warnings that the IDE shows (in text form, not as screen shots).

Comment: @AndrewThompson It fixed. Missed to add its package library; to StretchIcon.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to Java. Seems like the problem is not including its package name to the helper class (StretchIcon.java).

Like

package library;

to StretchIcon.java. Running the app without it causes runtime error and failing of netbeans to include some relevant elements to the compiled source.

Like

```
   package library; // <- this one. 

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

    public class StretchIcon extends ImageIcon {

      /**
       * Determines whether the aspect ratio of the image is maintained.
       * Set to <code>false</code> to allow th image to distort to fill the component.
       */
      protected boolean proportionate = true;

      /**
       * Creates a <CODE>StretchIcon</CODE> from an array of bytes.
       *
       * @param  imageData an array of pixels in an image format supported by
       *             the AWT Toolkit, such as GIF, JPEG, or (as of 1.3) PNG
       *
       * @see ImageIcon#ImageIcon(byte[])
       */
      public StretchIcon(byte[] imageData) {
        super(imageData);
      }

      /**
       * Creates a <CODE>StretchIcon</CODE> from an array of bytes with the specified behavior.
       *
       * @param  imageData an array of pixels in an image format supported by
       *             the AWT Toolkit, such as GIF, JPEG, or (as of 1.3) PNG
       * @param proportionate <code>true</code> to retain the image's aspect ratio,
       *        <code>false</code> to allow distortion of the image to fill the
       *        component.
       *
       * @see ImageIcon#ImageIcon(byte[])
       */
      public StretchIcon(byte[] imageData, boolean proportionate) {
        super(imageData);
        this.proportionate = proportionate;
      }

    }
```